# What is the most effective way to store 48-digit hex value in mongoDB?

Tags: string, mongodb, types, hex

I have unique 48-digit hexidecimal (192 bit) hash for one kind of objects, and, how I can see, mongo stores this values as strings. Is there a way to store it like numbers? Will storing it as numbers be more effective, than as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be simply the `binary` data type. It is efficient due to the fact that BSON format, in which MongoDB stores documents is a "Binary" JSON. 
The usage depends on the programming language you use.